# Why does a function always return undefined in JavaScript if return is not mentioned?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have recently started learning Javascript and want to understand how functions declared inside an object work.
i have defined a function inside an object and just logged a message "Function functionName is called" inside it.
When i call the function the console logs the message but along with it "undefined" also gets printed on the subsequent line.
i understand that my function doesn't return anything and hence by default javascript returns undefined.
But i need to know is there a way to write functions that return nothing similar to void functions() in java?

Here's my code -

```js
const circle = {
    radius : 5,
    location : {
        x: 10,
        y : 1
    },
    isVisible : true,
    draw : function(functionName){
        console.log('Function '+functionName+' is called. ');
    }
};

console.log(circle.isVisible);              // true
console.log(circle.radius);                 //  5
console.log(circle.location);               // { x: 1, y: 1 }
console.log(circle.location.x);             // 10      
console.log(circle.draw('draw'));
```

Comment: This is how JS is designed - there's no "non-existent" values, only `undefined`.

Comment: Every expression results in a value. If there’s no value, then it’s `undefined`. Why do you *need* something else?

Comment: "*But i need to know is there a way to write functions that return nothing similar to void functions() in java?*" note that in Java *the compiler* will stop you from capturing the return of `void`. There is usually enough information at compile time to determine if the result *should* be used (it's non-void) or not (is void). Wrong code just fails to compile. In JS you often don't have this information ahead of time. Therefore, this is unenforceable - you just have code that calls an unknown function. You're just not comparing Java and JavaScript equally - the situations are different.

Comment: I figured out what i needed to know. Actually the fact that i am calling the draw() inside console.log() is the reason it returns undefined. Anyway Thank you all !